# matplotlib figures are empty

Tags: python, matplotlib

I run this Python code: https://github.com/calculix/beso

### Config

The `beso_conf.py` file is modified. These variables:

```py
path_calculix = "C:\\Users\\m3\\Downloads\\calculix_2.21_4win\\ccx_static.exe" # path to the CalculiX solver
file_name = "C:\\Users\\m3\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\result.inp"  # file with prepared linear static analysis
cpu_cores = 1  # 0 - use all processor cores, N - will use N number of processor cores
```

### Run

```
cd C:\Users\m3\repos\beso               # Go to BESO repository folder
pip install virtualenv --user           # Install virtual env, also: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11845
python -m venv virtual_env              # Create a virtual env
virtual_env\Scripts\activate.bat        # Activate the virtual env
pip install numpy                       # Install a dependency
pip install matplotlib                  # Install another dependency
python beso_main.py                     # Run BESO. It uses `beso_conf.py` config file.
```

### Visualize

Assuming BESO went through 62 iterations, we can visualize the last iteration by:

```
c:\Users\m3\Downloads\calculix_2.21_4win\cgx_STATIC.exe -c file062_state1.inp
```

## Problem

For some reason the `matplotlib` Python figures are empty. But I cannot figure out why:

[image: Empty plot]

They should display how BESO iterations progress, like below:

[image: What plot should display]

Comment: Perusing the code in `beso_main.py` shows there should be more `print` statements; at the very least a final print statement indicating how long the script took. Perhaps the figure is empty simply because the script has yet to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the figure (or more which appear) and program should continue.